# Input data in nested x-for loops in Alpine.js V3 not binding to data

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Data binding in alpine.js works great when I do a single x-for loop wrapped around an HTML input tag. But, when I nest nested loops, the data entered in the inner loop inputs is not binding to the data object.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
<script>

book_data = { books: {
  a1: ['one', 'two', 'three' ],
  a2: ['four', 'five', 'six' ],
  a3: ['seven', 'eight', 'nine' ]
}
  };
</script>

<div x-data = "book_data">
  <template x-for="book in books">
    <div>
      <template x-for="number in book">
        <input x-model="number" type="text" />
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
  <button @click="console.log(book_data);">Submit</button>
</div>
```

If you click the button, you'll see the correct data in the console.  But, if you enter some values in the inputs, then click the button, those values won't be updated in the data object.

Note, I also need to add a repeater feature to this, but that might be a separate issue.

I know there must be some trickiness with nested loops in Alpine.js and the virtual variables it uses.  I'm using V3 of Alpine. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in the outer loop the variable *book* is an object and so is a reference to a row of *books*, in the inner loop the variable *number* is a copy of the array element.
To solve the problem we can address the element using the index:

```js
<template x-for="(number, ind) in book">  <!-- the inner loop -->
    <input x-model="book[ind]" type="text" />
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful and solves the issue! I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote!